# Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table &#03 (truncated

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've created an API using Laravel v5.8.
This API has one endpoint that recieve some parameters and create 1 row on a database table.
When I call to this endpoint using Postman, it works.

But...
I've create an App using Laravel 5.8 and when this app try to call to that API endpoint sending the same parameters, and headers, this error is showed:

**"Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table &#03 (truncated..."**

That table should be 'api_log', but i can't see this name in the error message.

**NOTE**: this error happens in the local environment only.

The Laravel app is using GuzzleHttp to call to the API.

**APP request:**

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('POST', 'http://project.local/v1/api_log', [
'headers' => [
'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Authorization' => $_ENV['API_TOKEN']
],
'form_params' => [
'json' => $json_request
]
]);
```

**MySQL statement in API controller** (no model is used):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO api_log (user_id, environment, start_datetime, end_datetime, requested_api, processing_time, activity_id, ip_address, request_data, response_data, credits) VALUES (".$user_id.",'".$env."','".$start_datetime."','".$end_datetime."',".$requested_api.",".$processing_time.",'".$activity_id."','".$ip_address."','".$request_data."','".$response_data."',".$credits.")";            

$insert_log = DB::connection('mysql_log')->statement($sql);
```

I've already tried to use a model like this but it didn't work:

```
class ApiLog extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql_log';
    protected $table = 'api_log';
}
```

I'm using normal http://localhost/... domains for the API and APP.
I've tried wrapping the API into a virtual host like http://project.local but the same error is showed.

Some clue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...after a lot of hours, I solved it watching the Laravel log file.

The problem was in .env file.

The .env file had this lines:

```
ALTER_CONNECTION=mysql_log
ALTER_HOST=127.0.0.1
ALTER_PORT=3306
ALTER_DATABASE=my_db
ALTER_USERNAME=root
ALTER_PASSWORD=my_pass
```

And I've changed it by:

```
ALT_CONNECTION=mysql_log
ALT_HOST=127.0.0.1
ALT_PORT=3306
ALT_DATABASE=my_db
ALT_USERNAME=root
ALT_PASSWORD=my_pass
```

I think these variables names were catched (I don't know why) so the DB config was failing.

Thank you all.

Comment: When in doubt:

`php artisan cache:clear`
`php artisan config:cache`... 


`config:cache` is mandatory when changing config files or .env files. Sometimes it works without, but usually it's better to just run it.

Answer (score 0):

It's sad I cannot comment. But it seems like you haven't specified connection `mysql_log` in your database config file. In order to use `$connection` or `DB::connection()` you have to specify the connection in `config/database.php`

In case you done this, check if your values are put correctly in the file. It is wise to use a different `constant` for the database/username/password than the other connection you're running through the app.

```
'connections' => [
    // New connection
    'mysql_log' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('MYSQL_LOG_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('MYSQL_LOG_PORT', '3306'),        
        'database' => env('MYSQL_LOG_DATABASE', 'DB2'),
        'username' => env('MYSQL_LOG_USERNAME', 'DB2'),
        'password' => env('MYSQL_LOG_PASSWORD', 'PASS'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],


    // Typical primary connection
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
]
```

After you added the connection to the config, you can run `php artisan config:cache` to ensure the new configurations are cached properly.

Comment: Thanks Tom, it's done. 
If I use postman to do a request to the API, it works fine. So the DB connection is working. The cache is already clear too.

Comment: But calling the API from the APP using Guzzle, it doesn't work in my local environment. It only works in the online server. I don't know why.

Comment: I think either the table is missing in your local environment or the database server isn't correctly pointed to in your configuration. Other than that I'm not really sure. Excuse me, didn't see you had already did the request in postman, so I'm not really helping. :(